# Is there any way to prevent Facebook::getLogoutUrl() logging out from Facebook.com?

Tags: php, facebook

How can I prevent loggin out from Facebook.com when I'm using [Facebook::getLogoutUrl](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLogoutUrl/)?

This is the code for the logout:

```
$next = 'ABSOLUTE_URL_TO_MY_INDEX_PAGE'; 
$facebookApi->destroySession();
$logoutUrl = $facebookApi->getLogoutUrl(array(
        'next' => $next,
            ));
header('Location: ' . $logoutUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I prevent loggin out from Facebook.com when I'm using Facebook::getLogoutUrl?

It’s the **purpose** of this method to also log the user out of Facebook.

And by [platform policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) you are **required** to have a link that does that:

> I. Features and Functionality, 6.: *Your website must offer an explicit "Log Out" option that also logs the user out of Facebook.*

Comment: Now this behavior makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`getLogoutUrl` does not redirect your users... What is actually redirecting your users is your `header('location: ...')` command.

Remove -

```
header('Location: ' . $logoutUrl);
```

Once you have the URL within the `$logoutUrl` variable, you can place it in an anchor tag and allow your users to log out by themselves...

```
<?php
  echo '<a href="'.$logoutUrl.'"  >Log out</a>';
?>
```

Comment: If I don't redirect to $logoutUrl then after I refresh my $next page, the Facebook PHP SDK gives me another Access Token.

Comment: By redirecting your users to that URL **you are logging them out of Facebook...**  I don't think I understand what the problem is here...

Comment: The problem is that when I'm going to the $logoutUrl it also clears the Facebook Session. So this is not what I wanted. I wanted just to invalidate the access token that I got from login, and to keep user's Facebook auth on Facebook.com.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by invalidating  the token?